# Prime quadruplets structure

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility

Why is it necessary to find a structure for the constellations of prime quadruplets such that they are not divisible by $2, 3$ or $5$ but not immediately worry about divisibility by $7$? Similarly, why consider $5$ as well? Why not just ensure they’re not divisible by $2$ and $3$? To be clear, I’m questioning where the ${30n+11, 30n+13, 30n+17, 30n+19}$ structure comes from.

Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Excellent, that answers my question. How can I accept that comment as a full answer please?

Comment: I wrote an answer, which you can accept if you want.

Comment: Sorry I was using the app which was clearly slow to update.

Comment: No problem , John.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to express the potential prime numbers as $\ an+b\ $. And additionally, $b$ should be less than $a$.

Now, if we take $a=6$, we cannot choose $4$ numbers of the form $\ 6n+b$ without having an odd and an even number, so we get only a prime-quartupel , if $2$ is one of the primes.

$a=30$ however works, and we can expect (although it has not been proven) that infinite many prime-quartuples exist. Since $30$ is sufficient, we do not need to consider the $7$ as well.